# TypeScript typings issue with redux-localstorage, persistState is not a function

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I want to persist redux stora in localstorage, using the redux-localstorage npm module. Issue is with TypeScript, as redux-localstorage does not have typings definitions.

So I wrote custom typings definition in `redux-localstorage.ts`:

```
declare module 'redux-localstorage' {
    module ReduxLocalStorage {
        export function persistState<A> (): any;
    }
    export = ReduxLocalStorage;
}
```

And when I create a redux store in `store.ts`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware } from "react-router-redux";
import { persistState } from "redux-localstorage";
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";

// Middleware
import logger from "./middleware/logger";
let ReduxThunk = require("redux-thunk").default;

// Reducers
import reducers from "./reducers/main";

export default function configureStore() {

    const createStoreWithMiddleware: any = compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            ReduxThunk,
            logger,
            routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
        ),
        persistState(),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )(createStore);

    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
    return {
        store,
        history: syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
    };
}
```

When I compile the project, everything seems fine, but when I try to load my application in Chrome, I get following error:

```
store.ts:21 Uncaught TypeError: redux_localstorage_1.persistState is not a function(…)configureStore @ store.ts:21(anonymous function) @ main.tsx:23__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap a9a3afb…:50(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js?a9a3afb…:6__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap a9a3afb…:50webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap a9a3afb…:21(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js?a9a3afb…:1
```

The typings declaration seems to work at least somehow, as before I wrote `redux-localstorage.ts` definition I got following error on project build:
`ERROR in ./src/store.ts
(3,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux-localstorage'.`

Comment: I found the issue, the import statement is incorrect. I should be importing a default member like import persistState from "redux-localstorage";, not the member import I had in my code. As redux-localstorage exports persistState function as a default export. But changing it this way, I get an TS error `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem even when using the typings module https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-localstorage

Comment: Unfortunately no, for now using without localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
import { persistState } from "redux-localstorage";
```

try

```
import * as persistState from "redux-localstorage";
```

Also you will not need to create a type definition file...